# R function to fill a degradation curve of a chemical using calculated decay rates

Tags: r, function

I am trying to fill a degradation curve of a chemical concentration using the decay rates I have calculated. I have a dataframe with columns for time and initial concentration, and I have calculated the decay rates as shown in line 4. Since the decay rate is more or less dinamic ( I have one for days between 0 and 7, from 7 to 13) every date interval should have an specific decay rate. Here's my code:

```
interpolate_ts <- function(dates, concentrations) {
  data <- data.frame(date = dates, conc = concentrations)
  data <- data[order(data$date), ]
  data$decay <- c(NA, diff(log(data$conc)) / diff(data$date))
  seq_dates <- seq(min(data$date), max(data$date), by = 1)
  interp_conc <- rep(NA, nrow(data))

  # Interpolate the concentrations for each date, if its in the input then the real one, if not calculate it, i suspect the problem is in here
  for (i in seq_along(seq_dates)) {
    if (seq_dates[i] %in% data$date) {
      interp_conc[i] <- data$conc[data$date == seq_dates[i]]
    } else {
      prev_date <- lag(seq_dates, n = 1, default = NA)
      prev_conc <- lag(interp_conc, n = 1, default = NA)
      decay <- data$decay[data$date == prev_date]
      interp_conc[i] <- prev_conc + (decay * prev_conc)
    }
  }
return(interp_conc)
}

times = c(0, 7, 13, 14, 21, 56)
obs_conc = c(1.9659406, 1.3826208, 0.8696116, 2.5825205, 1.6871537, 0.4838216)
ts_interp = interpolate_ts(times, obs_conc)
```

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything (it should explicitly have `return(interp_conc)` in the last line). In any case, it looks like you need regression rather than interpolation here.

Comment: Yeah I forgot sorry. I do not need regression. Every concentration shoulb be equal to the sum of the previous concentration and the product of the decay by the previous cponcentration (unless it was actually measured, the the real one should be there).

Comment: but your sample data is not continuously falling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
interpolate_ts <- function(dates, concentrations) {
  data <- data.frame(date = dates, conc = concentrations)
  data <- data[order(data$date), ]
  data$decay <- c(NA, diff(log(data$conc)) / diff(data$date))
  seq_dates <- seq(min(data$date), max(data$date), by = 1)
  interp_conc <- rep(NA, length(seq_dates))
  measure_numba <- 1:(nrow(data)-1)
  
  for (z in measure_numba) {
    start_date <- data$date[z]
    end_date <- data$date[z+1]
    decay <- data$decay[z+1]
    
    interp_dates <- seq(start_date, end_date, by = 1)
    interp_conc[seq_dates == start_date] <- data$conc[z]
    for (i in 2:length(interp_dates)) {
      prev_date <- interp_dates[i-1]
      prev_conc <- interp_conc[seq_dates == prev_date]
      next_conc <- prev_conc * exp(decay)
      interp_conc[seq_dates == interp_dates[i]] <- next_conc
    }
  }
  q = ggplot(data.frame(date = seq_dates, conc = interp_conc), aes(x = date, y = conc)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(x = "Date", y = "Concentration", title = "Degradation curve") +
    theme_bw()
  print(q)
  return(interp_conc)
}

dates <- c(0, 7, 13, 14, 21, 56)
concentrations <- c(1.9659406, 1.3826208, 0.8696116, 2.5825205, 1.6871537, 0.4838216)
ts_interp <- interpolate_ts(dates, concentrations)
```